Fluid Disappearing
i have a rigid body sphere rolling down a ramp and it is an inverse obstacle containing water(flip fluids)
as it rolls down the water disappears gradually
Video of bug
can someone help me please
thanks in advance

I do not own FLIP Fluids, but the main leak seems to happen as the fluid pushes up against the pole of the UV sphere, which has a lot of edges connecting to one vertex. I suspect the high edge connection count may be a weak point in the fluid collision detection, so I recommend you use an icosphere instead as it has uniform connecting edges. You may also have to turn up quality steps or other precision settings on the fluid simulation as well, though. As a general rule of thumb, more force means more simulation errors and instability, and the more precision needed.

Thanks for your help but, i attempted it with an ico sphere yet the issue presisted

You did rebake the cache and try adjusting the other settings, yes?

i rebaked with the same settings
